# How to verify value of text field in Symfony 1.4 functional tests

Tags: symfony-1.4, functional-testing

I am trying to use Symfony 1.4's functional tests (`sfTextFunctional`) to verify the value of a textfield is as I expect. This is the html that is generated

```
<input type="text" maxlength="10" name="number_plant[1]" value="5" id="number_plant_1">
```

During the test I can set the value easily

```
setField('number_plant[1]', '5')->
```

And I have tried the following permutations of checkelement but they all return null

```
checkElement('number_plant[1]',"5")->

checkElement('number_plant_1',"5")->

checkElement('#number_plant_1',"5")->

checkElement('form input[type="text"][name="number_plant[1]"]',"5")->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
checkElement('#number_plant_1[value="5"]')
```

EDIT: Apparently only this selector works as expected:

```
checkElement('form input[type="text"][name="number_plant[1]"][value="5"]')
```

(which is quite strange ;) )

This will check if an elemnt with `id = "number_plant_1"` and `value = "5"` exists on the page. As far as I know when you pass a string as the second parameter to `checkElement` it will try to match the content of the found element with the given string.

Comment: I tried both #number_plant_1[value="5"] and number_plant[1][value="5"] but both failed and said the element did not exist. I then got it to print out the contents of the page at that point and it definitely has `<input type="text" id="number_plant_1" value="5" name="number_plant[1]" maxLength="10">`

Comment: ha ah! The incantation that seems to work is `checkElement('form input[type="text"][name="number_plant[1]"][value="5"]')->` so fix up your answer and I'll mark it as correct